# Heatmap and sparklines

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, heatmap

I created an heatmap using [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/Bl3f/cdb5ad854b376765fa99) and this data:

```
NAME,YEAR,M1,M2
A,2000,20,5
B,2000,30,1
C,2000,,10
D,2000,,88
E,2000,,21
F,2000,84,3
G,2000,,64
A,2001,44,48
B,2001,15,51
C,2001,20,5
D,2001,95,2
E,2001,82,9
F,2001,,77
G,2001,3,80
A,2002,8,99
B,2002,92,52
C,2002,62,
D,2002,41,
E,2002,66,
F,2002,21,21
G,2002,62,4
A,2003,2,5
B,2003,89,78
C,2003,9,
D,2003,7,9
E,2003,2,45
F,2003,92,58
G,2003,2,14
A,2004,2,55
B,2004,89,58
C,2004,9,55
D,2004,7,59
E,2004,2,70
F,2004,92,
G,2004,2,
```

Now I would like to add to the right of the heatmap a sparkline for each row, so there must be a sparkline associated with A, to B, etc.
And I wish they were positioned right next to each other.

To make the sparklines I saw [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/1133472).

This is the result: [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MynwlNYWw5YeIsIEN06v).

[image]

As you can see, I can't get the data correctly from the `data.csv` file to create the sparklines. Also I don't know how to place them in the correct position.

I tried this way but without success.

```
var sparkSvg = d3.select("#container-sparkline")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .data(dataNest)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "sparkline-path")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            console.log("i");
            console.log(d);
        });
```

Also I'm not sure using two div is the correct way to put a chart near another chart.

Anyone would know how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach:**

I've created a sparkline for every name in data set with values on x axis as a `year` and y as a `m2` value from data set. For the demo purposes I've hardcoded number of years to 5 so x axis have only 5 values, but that can be computed with some additional script based on input data.
I've also added tome padding for sparkline container so they're aligned with the heatmap
[image]

**Code:**

As you can see in the plunker I've introduced a function to group data by name, so for each name we have an array with objects:

```
  var groupBy = function(array, key) {
    return array.reduce(function(a, v) {
      (a[v[key]] = a[v[key]] || []).push(v);
      return a;
    }, {});
  };
  // data grouped by name
  var groupedData = groupBy(data, 'name');
```

Since we assumed for demo purposes that X axis has fixed number of values we need to find max value for Y axis to properly scale charts. To do that I reduce array of values to get only `m2` values and find a max number whthin that array:

```
  var maxYvalue = Math.max(...data.map(function(d){return Number(d.m2)}));
```

Now we can create scales for the sparklines

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 4]).range([0, 60]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, maxYvalue]).range([2, itemSize-2 ]);
```

I'm assuming that chart have width of 60px and height of itemSize, I also introduce 2px of vertical padding so its easier to read those sparklines being on next to each-other.

Now we can define `d3.line`(as you already did in your plunker) which we'll use fro rendering sparklines .

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d); })
```

And last step is to render sparklines inside `"#container-sparkline"` container. To do that we can iterate over every array in `groupedData` and render sparkline for each name:

```
// for each name render sparkline
Object.keys(groupedData).forEach(function(key){

    const sparkData = groupedData[key].map(function(datum){
      return Number(datum['m2']);
    })

    var sparkSvg = d3.select("#container-sparkline")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", itemSize-1)
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "sparkline-path")
        .attr("d", line(sparkData));
})
```

I've also slightly changed styles for `#container-sparkline` and added borders for sparkline svg's. I hope this is what you've asked for.
Here you can find your plunker with my changes
http://plnkr.co/edit/9vUFI76Ghieq4yZID5B7?p=preview